# Scope Problem with Visual Assert

Tags: c++, visual-studio, scope

I'm trying to use Visual Assert for testing. Visual Studio says the method I want to test which is defined inside main.cpp is undefined in the Test Fixture.

MyFunctionTest.cpp:

```
#include <cfixcc.h>

class ExampleTest : public cfixcc::TestFixture
{
private:

public:
    void Test()
    {
        CFIXCC_ASSERT_EQUALS(4, MyFunction(2,2));
    }
};

CFIXCC_BEGIN_CLASS(ExampleTest)
    CFIXCC_METHOD(Test)
CFIXCC_END_CLASS()
```

I didn't make a separate project for tests so the two files are a part of the same project. How can I have MyFunction visible for Visual Assert to work properly?

Comment: Where is `MyFunctiony` defined?

Comment: MyFunction is defined in main.cpp. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

If non-technical circumstances beyond my control dictate that I am not allowed to move the definition to a header file, could I include the cpp file?

Comment: You don't need to move it to the header just declare it there. You can keep the definiton in main.cpp.

Comment: You can google for "C++ forward declaration".

Answer (score 0):

`#include` the header that declares `MyFunction()`